# If $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {a_n}$ converges absolutely, so does $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n^2}{2-a_n^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am struggling trying to prove (or refute) that statement. This is what I tried:

If $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {|a_n|}$ converges, one could easily find out that so does $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {a_n^2}$ using the fact that the former is bounded.

Then,

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {a_n^2} < C $$

Now the prove would conclude if I could state the following

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n^2}{|2-a_n^2|} < C $$

Which is not necessarily true from my point of view. Now is when I tried to find some counterexample but did not succeeded.

Any help is appreciated, and thank you for your time.

Comment: **Hint:** $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\,a_n=0$.

Comment: As @Batominovski said, for sufficiently large $n$ you have $|2-a_n^2| > 1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea follows what you said yourself. Since $|a_n|\to0$, there exists $n_0$ with $|a_n|<1$ for all $n>n_0$. Then $2-a_n^2>1$, and 
$$
\sum_{n>n_0}\frac{|a_n|^2}{2-a_n^2}\leq\sum_{n>n_0}|a_n|<\infty.
$$